# Added geom_smooth layer to a plot object in ggplot2 (Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I get an error of:
`Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?`
When I do the following mapping (with "Smooth" specifically):

```
plot.type <- switch(input$plot.type, 
                          "Boxplot"=geom_boxplot(aes(group=1)), 
                          "Histogram"=geom_histogram(alpha=0.5, position="identity"), 
                          "Density"=geom_density(alpha=0.75), 
                          "Bar"=geom_bar(position="dodge"), 
                          "Scatter"=geom_point(aes_string(x=plot.obj$group, 
                                                          y=plot.obj$variable)),
                          "Smooth"= geom_point(aes_string(x=plot.obj$group, 
                                                          y=plot.obj$variable)) + geom_smooth(aes(group=1)))
```

Essentially I am adding to a base ggplot defined as such, and it is from a plot object I created in the shiny server. I tried out the following code on a data.frame and it worked fine. I'll include that code and the desired output below.
I'd appreciate any tips as to where I went wrong. From looking at other posts with the same error I suspect it is due to how I got the data as a plot object.

```
data_1 <- read.csv("~/DATA/plot.csv")

p <- ggplot(data_1, aes(
                x=Number.of.trucks.arrived,
                y=Number.of.replenishment.orders.to.Pickface))
p <- p + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
p
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: For the `"Smooth"` option in switch, you should return a `list` of the two layers instead of using the `+` operator (which works with plot and layer, or plot and list, but not layer and layer).

Comment: I now wrapped "Smooth" into a list and now I add plot.type as a list to the ggplot layer for output. However it now is showing and error (stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y). Could you clarify the above slightly, through an example?
Changes made:
"Smooth"=list(geom_point(aes_string(x=plot.obj$group, 
                                                          y=plot.obj$variable)), geom_smooth())  

I then added the list plot.type to the ggplot layer.

Comment: I don't know how you're using the `plot.type` object in your post so I can't reproduce this error. The list thing just occurred to me by eyeballing the code. Can you show a full example with (dummy) data of how you intend to use the `plot.type` object without the shiny bits (as the problem appears to be just a ggplot2 problem).

Comment: Turns out I was overlooking an obvious issue with my code. Your suggestion  of creating a list object solved the issue fully. I accidentally messed up the structure of the if else statements when making the edit resulting in an else statement overriding the base ggplot layer creation. Thank you for the help @teunbrand.